# Em PHP, qual a melhor maneira para imprimir uma variável através de uma função?

Tags: php, echo

Vamos supor que tenho a seguinte função:

```
private function teste()
{
    return 'teste';
}
```

Para que eu imprima na tela, eu poderia simplesmente utilizar:

```
echo $this->teste();
```

Porém em alguns casos eu vejo que primeiro atribuem a uma variavel e somente após isso imprimem, da seguinte forma:

```
$variavel = $this->teste();
echo $variavel;
```

Criar uma copia(variável) desnecessária do resultado da função não seria desperdício de processamento e memória?

Em quais casos devemos utilizar diretamente e atribuindo a uma variável?

Comment: A sua função `teste` não retorna nada, e mesmo que se retornasse por exemplo a string 'teste', a variavel de dentro da função logo ia ser liberada da memória assim que a função acabasse, consequentemente não teria problema com desperdicio de memória.

Comment: Acabei me confundindo. O correto é dar um return e não echo na função teste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private function teste()
{
    echo 'teste';
}
```

Esse método apenas imprime algo não retorna valor, para a seguinte linha fazer sentido

```
$variavel = $this->teste();
```

Você deve alterar o método teste para a seguinte forma

```
private function teste()
{
    return 'teste';
}
```

E em relação ao desperdício de memória você estaria enganado pois assim que o método ou função chegar ao primeiro return ou no final do seu corpo, todos as variaveis que estão no seu escopo seriam liberados da memória.
Variaveis declaradas dentro de uma função são chamadas de variáveis locais da função. Para saber mais pesquise sobre escopo de variáveis.

**De acordo com a atualização da descrição da pergunta**, você sempre atribui um valor a uma variável quando você tem a intenção de reutilizá-lo mais de uma vez, ou também para deixar o código mais legivel.

Atribuir a uma variável apenas para dar mais legibilidade não seria desperdício de memória,  pois como eu disse as variaveis apenas vai estar em memória enquanto o contexto em que ela estiver sido declarada, estiver sendo executado (exemplo uma função ou método).
Se fosse algumas décadas atrás, a resposta seria sim devido as limitações do hardware, mas hoje isso não é problema, a legibilidade do código é mais importante.

Comment: Me confundindo ao escrever a função. O correto é dar um return em uma string como você mesmo disse.

Comment: Ok. De memória não teria desperdício, porém desperdício de processamento, fazendo o PHP armazenar o retorno da função "teste" na variável de nome "variavel"? Aí que surge minha dúvida de imprimir direto da função em relação a criar uma nova variavel para atribuir o retorno a ela para só após isso imprimir.

Comment: Não é beeem um função, tem mais cara de ser um método por ter um `private` antes do nome.

Comment: Perfeito. Como você mesmo disse: "você sempre atribui um valor a uma variável quando você tem a intenção de reutilizá-lo mais de uma vez, ou também para deixar o código mais legível.". Exatamente em utilizar apenas pra ser legível que parei pra pensar se realmente isso trairia desperdício de performance, sendo que o PHP teria que atribuir um valor a uma variável sem necessidade. Obviamente se ela for utilizada posteriormente, seria necessário utiliza-la. O escopo da variável tem algo a ver com essa parte de performance? Não existe uma copia de valor na memoria como estou pensando?

Answer (score 2):

```
private function teste()
{
    echo 'teste';
}
```

O método teste imprime um valor, e não retorna nada, logo, `echo $this->teste()` é a mesma coisa que `$this->teste()`.

```
$variavel = $this->teste();
echo $variavel;
```

No exemplo acima, você imprime *teste*, mas não pelo `echo $variavel`, mas sim pelo método pois contém `echo 'teste'`. no seu exemplo `$variavel` é `null` pois o método não retornou nada.

Fiz um exemplo no [*ideone*](http://ideone.com/8OH9Ga), você pode ver a variavel como `null`.

Comment: Me confundi ao escrever a pergunta. O correto é return no lugar do echo dentro da função teste.

Answer (score 1):

Depende do caso, se for apenas imprimir o valor não tem porque fazer a atribuição à uma variável. Basta `echo $this->teste()`.

Se o retorno do método for utilizado depois para um calculo ou outra operações faz sentido sim jogar o resultado em uma variável.

```
$res = $this->teste();
$res = formataAlgo($res);
if($res ...) ...
echo $res;
```

Comment: Exatamente isso. O problema é que muitas pessoas atribuem o valor do retorno da função para uma variável pra deixar o código mais organizado quando o nome da função for utilizado em diferentes algoritmos, corrigindo criando uma nova variável com um nome mais apropriado. Ai então que está minha dúvida: isso seria desperdício de processamento e memória então?